# "Assign" one image to multiple faces no longer working

Tags: texturing, uv, uv-image-editor

Up until recently I was able to select multiple faces of a mesh, even faces with different images selected in the **UV/Image** Editor tab, and select for them  them a different image all at once by selecting that image from the linked image dropdown.

Right now if three selected faces have three different images "assigned", I have to go to each one and change it to the new one instead of all at once.

Is there a setting I accidentally changed to make it work like this?

**Edit:**

[image]

Comment: I have tried it now in Blender 2.78a - I have selected 3 faces with different UV/Image image assigned, selected all faces in UV editor and changed the image. All 3 faces have now correctly assigned that new image. Can you check you don't have the current image pinned in the UV editor menu bar?

Comment: @JanKadeřábek, yes the image isn't pinned. I'm using Blender 2.78a. [Here is a screenshot after I selected two "differently-imaged" faces and changed the image.](http://imgur.com/a/r17zj) Very odd. I have no problem changing one image to another, it's just when more than one is selected, only one (the last image selected) will be changed

Comment: can you upload the blend with the issue?
http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com

Comment: Ok, added to the original post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have checked UV Local View which causes you always see only those faces that have assigned the image currently opened in the UV/Image editor. So when you try to replace the image, even if you press A (thinking you have all faces in the editor), you always replace only that one image.
[image]

Uncheck it and it will work :-)

Comment: Haha, that was it! I knew I accidently clicked *something*. Thanks so much

Comment: I just actually learned what is this checkbox for because of your problem -thanks! :D